# Running multiple glm models on mixed data with purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Suppose we have a toy data set:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

tbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
              b = rep(c(0, 1), times = 5),
              c = runif(10),
              d = rexp(10)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(1,2), as.factor)
```

where `a` is a dependent variable and `b:d` are independent variables. The idea is to run `glm` model for each independent variable:

- `glm(a ~ b, data = tbl, family = "binomial")`
- `glm(a ~ c, data = tbl, family = "binomial")`
- `glm(a ~ d, data = tbl, family = "binomial")`

My initial attempt goes as follows:

```
tbl %>%
    pivot_longer(2:4, names_to = "key", values_to = "val") %>%
    group_split(key) %>%
    map(~ glm(a ~ val, data = .x, family = "binomial"))
```

This resulted in an error because data types of `b` and `c` (or `d`) are not the same.

```
Error: No common type for `b` <factor<dec08>> and `c` <double>.
```

I wonder how to address this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without reshaping, we can use `map` to apply `glm` to various independent variables and use `reformulate` to create the formula like :

```
purrr::map(names(tbl)[-1],~glm(reformulate(.x, 'a'),data = tbl,family = 'binomial'))

#[[1]]

#Call:  glm(formula = reformulate(.x, "a"), family = "binomial", data = tbl)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           b1  
#    -0.4055       0.8109  

#Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
#Null Deviance:     13.86 
#Residual Deviance: 13.46   AIC: 17.46

#...
#...
```

Comment: I have edited my question and add an argument `family = "binomial"` as appropriate.

Comment: @Andrej Actually, the answer doesn't change much. You add the same argument in the answer. `purrr::map(names(tbl)[-1], ~glm(reformulate(.x, 'a'), data = tbl, family = 'binomial'))`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: alternatively `map(setdiff(names(tbl),"a"), reformulate, response="a") %>% map(glm, data=tbl, family=binomial)`