# Pass pipe output directly to purrr map function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

This question is in line with my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598466/running-multiple-glm-models-on-mixed-data-with-purrr). However, I try to combine the output of the pipe call with `purrr`'s map function into a single pipeline. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

my_tbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
             b = rep(c(0, 1), times = 5),
             c = runif(10),
             d = rexp(10)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(1,2), as.factor)

map(names(my_tbl)[-1], ~glm(reformulate(.x, "a"), data = my_tbl, family = "binomial")) %>% summary()
```

I tried with

```
my_tbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
             b = rep(c(0, 1), times = 5),
             c = runif(10),
             d = rexp(10)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(1,2), as.factor) %>%
    {map(names(.)[-1], ~glm(reformulate(.x, "a"), data = ., family = "binomial")) %>% summary()}
```

but I got:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

Comment: Really minor, but `purrr` is loaded already by loading `tidyverse`, so you don't need to do that explicitly. Or, even better, just load the tidyverse packages you need so there's less overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need purrr in this case:

```
custom_fun <- function(x) {
  glm(reformulate(names(x)[-1], "a"), data = x, family = "binomial") %>% 
    summary
}

my_tbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
                 b = rep(c(0, 1), times = 5),
                 c = runif(10),
                 d = rexp(10)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(1,2), as.factor) %>% 
  custom_fun()
```

You could use purrr with the following:

```
my_tbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
                 b = rep(c(0, 1), times = 5),
                 c = runif(10),
                 d = rexp(10)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(1,2), as.factor) %>% 
  nest(data = everything()) %>% 
  mutate(res = map(data, custom_fun))
```